# Algorithm for infinite graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, qwt

I need to implement an "infinite graph", but I have no idea how exactly to make the algorithm for doing so.

I'm using Qt with Qwt where all my points are stored in a `QVector<double>`; when new data arrives, it is appended to the end of the vector. Different from a classic graph, where all data shown on screen is updated at some point, the infinite graph theoretically stores all data received since the plotting started. This produces an effect of "reducing the curve as it comes to the left of the plot", such as in this image:
[image: plot].

But I can't maintain all data inside the points vector since there is no infinite pixels on screen; I need to remove one point each time a new one arrives.

But how to do that in a way that will produce the "infinite graph" effect? I think I can't just randomly remove a point from any part of the curve when new data arrives; that certainly will not create the "getting smaller" effect.

I thought about the idea of removing a point AND making all remaining points receive a minor value that the one they posses (so when each new data arrives, all already existing points will receive a -1 in their x Values), but I'm not sure that will work. Does anybody have any ideas?

**EDIT**

Some users did some questions down below, and here are my answers:

Steve: No; the x-axis is not constantly changing to equal the number of the total points received; this is only what it SHOULD look like, since it's supposed to be a graph showing "all" the data received. But the screen is size-limited and, therefore, the x-axis will also be size-limited since I don't pretend to plot more then one point per pixel available on the screen (570, to be more specific). Now have some point in mind: by saying that the x-axis will be size-limited doesn't mean that it will necessarily have a scale 0-570; the scale values themselves might change, but the vectos containing the points to be plotted will be size fixed since I don't want to store a 100.000 points vector inside my embedded application!

quantdev: A "infinite graph" is a graph that theoretically plots all data received since the start of the plotting, contrary to what fixed-time graphs shows (which plots, lets say "the data received in the last 10 seconds"). But obviously that's pure theory, since there is not an infinite size screen to show all the points, nor there is enough memory to store an infinite size vector of points. So what I would want is to maintain a minimum size vector with the points to be plotted (which I take to be equal to the number of pixels on screen) and still have the infinite graph effect. More, the graph must have the effect shown on the attached image: the older the data, the smaller is becomes on the plot (note: but in the contrary position to the image, since the drawing will be right-to-left).

Tay2510: there you go! And just to be sure, there will be no sliding effect as in a oscilloscope; the graph will be x-axis-fixed.

Comment: So, you're saying that your x-axis scale is constantly changing? The left side is always zero, and your right side is always whatever the last sample was?

Comment: What is the "infinite graph" effect exactly ?

Comment: @Momergil Please respond to Steve and quantdev's questions in the comment first, if you really want a helpful answer. We are not 100% sure whether you want an effect of squeezing data with increasing index of axis, or sliding like real-time data stream in an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 2):

Don't remove one point at a time. That becomes rather messy, mathematically. You have to interpolate too often, which leads to a loss of numerical precision.

Instead, keep adding points to your vector until the size is twice as large as you need it to be. At that point, average all point pairs to halve the vector the length. I.e. the new `x[3]`  is the old `(x[6]+x[7])/2`.

To draw, don't use the `x[]` directly, as you generally have too many points. Instead you must interpolate between 2 adjacent points.

Comment: I like the idea. Btw, for the last sentence (To draw...), did you mean to halve the halved vector again, or you just paraphrased the previous paragraph?

Comment: @Tay2510: No, interpolation is a specific mathematical procedure. If you have 317 points in x[] but you need to draw only 256 points, you multiply your index i by 317.0/256.0. For instance, to draw the 42nd point, you'd want `x[52.01]`. Now clearly that point doesn't exist, so you use `x[52]*99/100 + x[53]*1/100`

Answer (score 1):

> I think I can't just randomly remove a point from any part of the curve when new data arrives; that certainly will not create the "getting smaller" effect.

This is right. The first step you should take is increase the width of the amount of points on the X axis to the maximum amount. When you did that you remove the points with the smallest deviation from the Y axis between larger ones when you need to.

These points will create the smallest amount of graphical change in your graph while the ones with the largest deviation will be far more visible when pushed against one another.

> I thought about the idea of removing a point AND making all remaining points receive a minor value that the one they posses (so when each new data arrives, all already existing points will receive a -1 in their x Values), but I'm not sure that will work.

This would put make the graph slide to the left which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed-memory solution to this class of problems has been beaten to death on digital phosphor oscilloscopes.

What you do is:

1. Begin with a fixed-size `QImage` for the graph, where every incoming sample results in a point plotted, and there's *one* X coordinate per sample. Plot samples left-to-right. There's no need to store the values anywhere else: the image is your storage.
2. When you run out of sample space horizontally, resize the contents of the existing image to half its horizontal size, aligned to the left, and clear the right half of the image.
3. Plot new incoming samples from the midpoint onwards - over the cleared part of the image.
4. Go to 2.

Options:

- Change the split point to be something else than half of the horizontal size.
- Re-plot the scales without storing any extra data but a division counter - the division counter is enough to know exactly where all the division points were etc.
- Before scaling the image in step 2, you can re-scale the *intensity* values on the image that you're about to scale by a factor of 0.5. This way, you'll get a phosphor-like effect for each pixel, where pixels with overlapping samples are more intense.
- The intensity scaling can be saturating, so that, for example, you never zero any intensity below 1/255. This avoids eventual disappearance of pixels. You can, in fact, choose even fancier non-linear and time-variant scalings, according to your tastes.